# Loops in C challenge: can it be done another way?

Tags: c, algorithm, loops

Hi all C experts (please don't shoot, I'm no C programmer anymore but from time to time I have a question that pops in my mind)

I was reading another question ([How to print an entered string backwards in C using only a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331347/how-to-print-an-entered-string-backwards-in-c-using-only-a-for-loop)).

The "simplest" and most logical answer is

```
for (x = end; x >= 0; --x) {
    printf("%c", word[x]);
}
```

But I was wondering if there wasn't a way to achieve the same goal but staying closer to the original loop poseted:

```
for (x = word[end]; x >= word[0]; x--) {
    printf("%c", x);
}
```

I don't know enough C to work it out, but couldn't we play with the arrays pointers to loop through

```
char * wordp;
for(wordp = &word[end]; /*something*/; wordp--){\
   printf("%c", &wordp);
}
```

P.S.: I don't really care if it is a forwards or backwards loop.

P.P.S.: Sorry if I made obvious C mistakes in the pointers; point them out in the comment and I'll edit them.  ;)

Jason

Comment: Sure you can, and it may be more efficient since increments are faster than additions on some architectures. A good compiler should generate the same code with both approaches though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely.

```
char *wordp;

for(wordp = word + end; wordp >= word; wordp--){
   printf("%c", *wordp);
}
```

Comment: ... and that's how STL iterators are used

Comment: I must say I have to admire the possibilities of C :P. what I was missing is how to compare wordp >= word, I know pointers a fundamentally numbers and can be compared but I didn't know that they were necessarily ordered from smaller to bigger in a array (sounds logical thought lol). can this trick be puller with dynamical arrays/list? actually is the >= necessary ? could you simply put it == ?

Comment: @Jason: Due to the nature of the structure and the loop, we need to treat it as a boundary condition, not an event condition.

Comment: And note that you actually save one addition per iteration doing it this way !

Answer (score 1):

```
for (x = word[end]; x >= word[0]; x--) {
    printf("%c", x);
}
```

will not work, as word[end] is equivalent to *(word + end).  It's already being dereferenced, so x will be set to the value of the last char, and will loop until it equals the char value of the first char.  In short, it makes no sense.

Try:

```
char * wordp;
for(wordp = (word + end); wordp >= word; wordp--){\
   printf("%c", *wordp);
}
```

Remember that an array is simply a pointer to its first item.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
    char * wordp;
    for(wordp = &word[end]; wordp >= word ; wordp--){\
            printf("%c", *wordp);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Real programmers use recursion:

```
void revputs(char *s) {
  if (*s) { revputs(s + 1); putchar(*s); }
}
```

Comment: REAL programmers use recursion when needed and they don't feel the need to brag about it. otherwise good solution ^^